# batch file which uses windows OS date

Tags: batch-file

I every month a get a folder named using the year and month (which am not allowed to change). For instance DB201401 (DB = database, 2014 = the year and 01 =the month). I was wondering if there was a way to make a batch file, which finds the correct folder of the same year and month based on windows OS Date?

or maybe just find the folder by the month, ignoring the "DB2014"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "curdt=%%a"
set "Year=%curdt:~0,4%" 
set "Month=%curdt:~4,2%" 
echo DB%YEAR%%MONTH%
```

Change the echo to whatever you want to do with the foldername.

This depends on WMI - so it won't work on very very old Windows versions without WMI.

Comment: here you can replace the two `set`statements with `set folder=DB%curdt:~0.6`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that just be the latest "DB2*" directory date?

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad DB2*') do set currdir=%%a&goto done
:done
echo %currdir%
```

- but that assumes that the only `DB2*` directories are of format `DBccyymm`